# Problem with pure function for operating on text

Tags: functions

I have this code:

```
text = "Today I woked up early"
cadena = InputForm[StringSplit[text]]
out:{"Today", "I", "woked", "up", "early"}
```

Why don't work this?

```
"\"#\"" & /@ {Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday}
out:{"#", "#", "#", "#","#"}
```

The pure function only work with numbers?

Comment: You probably want either `"\"" <> ToString[#] <> "\"" & /@ {Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, 
  Thursday, Friday}` or `ToString[#] & /@ {Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday}`.

Comment: Yes I may sound as a grammar nazi, but heck I could't resist it. _Today I_ `woke up` _early_ is more accurate :p

Answer (score 10):

Outside of quotes, `#` is shorthand for `Slot[]`, but in quotes it's only a character. So, don't quote it:

```
"\"" <> SymbolName[#] <> "\"" & /@ {Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday,Thursday, Friday}
(* {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"} *)
```